# DocuSignAPI embedded signing redirect URL

Tags: php, wordpress, docusignapi

I have integrated DocuSignAPI in WordPress and it's also working well but once sign completed page is not redirect properly. It's showing in iframe. I want to redirect page out of iframe.

I have used same code from [EmbeddedSigning.php](https://github.com/docusign/devcenter-quickstarts/blob/master/2-EmbeddedSigning/EmbeddedSigning.php).

And my redirect page code is:

```
 // instantiate a RecipientViewRequest object
$recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();

// set where the recipient is re-directed once they are done signing
$recipient_view_request->setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com/develcenter");

// configure the embedded signer 
$recipient_view_request->setUserName($recipientName);
$recipient_view_request->setEmail($recipientEmail);

// must reference the same clientUserId that was set for the recipient when they 
// were added to the envelope in step 2

$recipient_view_request->setClientUserId("1234");

// used to indicate on the certificate of completion how the user authenticated
$recipient_view_request->setAuthenticationMethod("email");

// generate the recipient view! (aka embedded signing URL)
$signingView = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId, $envelop_summary->getEnvelopeId(), $recipient_view_request);
echo "Signing URL = " . $signingView->getUrl() . "\n";
```

But page is not redirect properly it's still showing in iframe.

So how could I redirect page out of iframe?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: @LarryK, Yes, i  resolved it  Thank You!

Comment: @SamirSheikh Would you please post your solution as an answer here? It will help the others looking for similar solution. BTW, https://github.com/docusign/devcenter-quickstarts/blob/master/2-EmbeddedSigning/EmbeddedSigning.php is no longer working.